# tensorflow tries to calculate gradients that arent relevant to the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

My net is not working how its supposed to, so i was trying to remove parts of the loss function. Instead of now ignoring the parts that are not needed anymore tensorflow still tries to cumute gradients which come out to none and break the code.

How can i effectivley remove parts from the loss calculation without removing entire parts of the code?

This is what it looks like:

```
variable_scope(image_generation)
  convolutions
  upconvolutions with output

variable_scope(pose_estimation)
  convolutions with output

loss a = calculation similarity between input and image_generation
loss b = calculation other factors between input and image_generation
loss c = calculation from pose_estimation

total_loss = a + b + c -> changed to total_loss = a

opt_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
loss = model.total_loss
grads = opt_step.compute_gradients(loss)
```

grads now still contain parts that are irrelevant to a

Comment: You can pass to the optimizer the list of variables you want to optimize, apart from that your question is not specific enough so we cannot answer.

Comment: @jean i added some more information, i hope its clearer now